# Highchart the horizontal gradline below the 0 axis

Tags: highcharts

[image]

I want the gradline and the xaxis started in the same line, I tried set the yaxis.min and so on。
it don't work, so some one could help me on this?

```
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'text'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [],
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        width: '50px',
                        'min-width': '50px'
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                categories: [],
                title: {
                    text: 'text'
                },
                min: 0,
            },
            series: [
                {
                    name: 'name',
                    type: 'spline'
                }
            ]
```

This is my chart option, and I dynamicly update the values of xAxis and yAxis, this's my update code

```
            chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(0, maxy);
            chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(timeArr);
            chart.series[0].setData(valArr);
```

timeArr is the string array about time, valArr is my data, maxy is max of the valArr.

Comment: When I open any demo on Highcharts site, they have aligned that. Show us your options for a chart, and we will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your mention it, I updated my question, added the option of my chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/bteWs/31/ (try to update to 4.0.1 version)

However, I advice to remove categories from yAxis, since you want numeric values, right?

```
        yAxis: {
            categories: [], //remove that option
            title: {
                text: 'text'
            },
            min: 0,
        },
```

Comment: I just remove the categories, it worked, so amazing. but I still don't know why it works, the api document of categories, don't mention it will affect the gride line.

Comment: My example works fine (see demo), so I guess you have old version of Highcharts, which had bug with that gridline.

Comment: Yes, I used old version 3.0.7 because of the project reason. It looks like old version issue.

Comment: Yes, it's fixed in 4.0+ versions.